# how do i get larger thumbnail for youtube from api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've been using the Youtube API to grab thumbnail images of selected videos but I need them to be a little bigger.

I need  thumbnails at a larger size, at the moment I can generate only smaller images.

I was just wondering if anyone had found a way to generate slightly larger thumbnails

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cj6ho1-G6tw/1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your are looking for: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Also to get them from API instead of hardcoding it, you can check my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16798323/1973552